# Object position issue in threejs when replacing object in a scene

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, blender, threejs-editor

I Want to replace an object (objectToBeReplace) from the threejs scene, with the newObject.

I have written the function below.

```js
export const replaceObject = async (
  objectToBeReplace,
  newObj,
  scene
) => {

  //update matrix world of the object
  objectToBeReplace.updateMatrixWorld(true);
  objectToBeReplace.updateMatrix();


    //replace object with the newobject with the same position and rotation
   newObj.position.copy(objectToBeReplace.position.clone());
   newObj.rotation.copy(objectToBeReplace.rotation.clone());
   newObj.scale.copy(objectToBeReplace.scale);
   newObj.quaternion.copy(object.quaternion);
 

  objectToBeReplace.parent.add(newObj);
  objectToBeReplace.parent.remove(objectToBeReplace);
  newObj.updateMatrixWorld(true);
  newObj.updateMatrix();
 

  console.log("object replaced");
};
```

I want to replace the cooker from the scene with the newCooker.

Before Replacement

[image: Before Replacement]

After Replacement
[image: After Replacement]

Link for the model
https://o.convrse.ai/pgLMzNwabk-0/low/W0a17ghen08x/armchair-cooker_DFSZa8q2zf95wQ6eFdZTD_optimized.glb

I am able to replace the object, buts it's position and orientation is getting changed. I want to retain its position and orientation.

Are there any extra parameters in the `Mesh` or `Geometry` which affects the position and orientation of the object ?.

Comment: One solution is to add the object as the child of another, geometry-less, object, such as a `Group`. You apply your transformations not to the cooker object, but to the Group object. When you then remove the cooker and add another object to the Group's children, it will retain the same transformations.